# Getting ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) Using Python 3.6.3 and Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

Hi I'm new with python and OpenCV. With the code below I'm trying to stream from a web camera and detect circles. I'm trying to extract the center of the circle and the radius in the for loop and then draw the circle. Every time I do that I get the following error.

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Any help about why the code dosnt work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while(True):
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),5)
    circ = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,
                              minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
    for(x,y,r) in circ:
        cv2.circle(gray,int(x),int(y),int(r),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.imshow('video',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==27:# esc Key
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> Edit: The Traceback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Documents/pythonproj/webcameratest.py", line 11, in 
>       for(x,y,r) in circ:
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I don't think that `cv2.circ` is a valid OpenCV function in Python API. Also it would be helpful if you paste the full error traceback, which includes the line number where the error is happening.

Comment: @ZdaR I meant to use cv2.circle in the code to dray a circle around where it detected one. but it is still making the same error. Also a added the full trackback.

Comment: So if you see the error closely it states that: `for(x,y,r) in circ: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`, which clearly means that `cv2.HoughCircles()` is simply returning `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
circ = np.uint16(np.around(circ))
for i in circ[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(gray, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

instead of:

```
for(x,y,r) in circ:
    cv2.circle(gray,int(x),int(y),int(r),(0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: I changed that but, now I'm now getting any error, but it takes a while for the script to load a frame from the camera.

Comment: My bad, I meant to I'm not getting an error anymore, but it takes a long time for the script to load the image from the webcamera, and when it does load it its just a still not a stream.

Comment: I don't think that issue is relevant to this question. So it is highly recommended to come up with a new question. I hope you got the answer for this question. :)

Comment: Best way to thank is accept this answer as correct :)

Comment: Yeah I figured out what this question was trying to answer. Thanks for the help.